# How To Create Custom Table Cells With That Pulls Data From An SQLite Database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, tableview

I have been searching the internet for a long time trying to figure this out. I want to create a social networking app that allows me to have custom table cells that pulls data from an sqlite database. I want the users profile pic to be added to the left of the table cell and their username to be added to the right of the cell. I know I will need an image view that pulls a BLOB image from the sqlite database and I know I need a label to display the username. I also want this to be updated in real time like facebook and twitter. I already have my sqlite database created and the user interface designed. I just dont know where to go from there. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to fire a query get the data before you display your `UITableView`.
2. Result of this query will decide the number of rows in your `UITableView`
3. Whenever you'll get update or want to change the content of the `UITableView` only thing you need to do is fire the query again. Get the data from your SQLite. And, reload your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Pull the data from the database into memory.

I use Core Data to do this and [**here**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good start point.
You can [**fetch records**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/05_Fetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH107-SW1) from sqlite and change them into objects, so you can manipulate them.

## 2 Layout a tableView on your view

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW11) to know how to add a tableView.

The key method for you is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
You will custom your cell in it.
Know that `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are very important to understand for using UITableView.

## 3 Custom your own UITableViewCell

You can create a subclass of UITableViewCell, maybe MyTableViewCell, to show the user's avatar and name.
Or you can just use the default UITableViewCell, for it has a imageView and a label, which meets your need.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    // Do something here
    cell.imageView.image = user.avatar;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = user.name;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method which may  consist the code to fetch data and reload the table. Then create NSTime trigger and call the method